# CSS color transition triggers multiple animations when loading the website

Tags: css, css-transitions

This is my first question in this forum so if it's not well explained, feel free to ask me for more details.

I have a color transition in all the links on my navbar, that triggers when you hover your mouse over them. This work wells, the problem is that when the website loads, all those elements began to resize or move to their initial positions.

CSS

```
nav{
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(250,250,250,1);
    font-size: 13px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D8D8D8;
    color: #6E6E6E;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: -80px;
}

nav a{
    padding: 20px 20px;
    line-height: 80px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.8s;
    transition: all 0.8s;   
}

nav a:hover{
    color:#00BFFF;
}
```

---

UPDATE

I have tried to make a JSFiddle with the problem, but even when the CSS and HTML is exactly the same its seem to work correctly [on the demo](https://jsfiddle.net/alvarado87/aaweLpx4/)

I have changed the transition property from *all* to *color*. This has solved the problem partially, since now the elements don't move when the page loads, but the problem now is that all links that include this color transition, when the website loads, show an initial blue color (inexistent in my CSS) taking the transition time to change to the correct color. This initial blue color is similar to the visited links standard color (but I have also used the selector *a:visited* without positive result.

This only happens on Firefox.

As due to my low reputation I can't post images, I have taken the blue initial tone: RGB (6,6,231)

Comment: Could you share your entire code on JSfiddle?

Comment: Can you be clearer in your question? What do you mean by "all this elements began to resize and move to their initial positions"? Are you certain that it is caused by having a color-transition in your navbar? i.e. when you took it out, you don't observe "all this elements began to resize and move to their initial positions".

Answer (score 0):

You only need animate the color:

```
-webkit-transition: color 0.8s;
transition: color 0.8s;
```

note that I change *all* for *color* only.

note 2 you can do

```
transition: color 0.8s, height 0.2s ease-out, opacity 1s linear 0.5s;
```

Comment: Thank you Raul, after animating only color half of the problem has been solved. I will post an update on the question with actual status.

Comment: Hey, the example works well. Can you tell me 1 things:
Are you using any CSS Framework?

Comment: Yeah in the example works well, is weird... I'm using Sublime Text 2. Sorry for the delay in my answer, and thanks for your help!

Comment: Try reproduce the problem in a fiddler and maybe we can help you

Comment: @Alvarado87, do you find the solution to the problem?

Comment: Not yet, I didn't have much time to look into it yet though... I will try to reproduce the problem in a fiddler and show it to you (but there seems to work fine...). Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding script tag at footer of the html page.This worked for me.

```
<script> </script>
```